# How to convert torch.norm to cosine distance

Tags: pytorch, torch, cosine-similarity

I want to change norm distance to cosine distance, help me convert this function to cosine distance

```
def feat_prototype_distance(self, feat):
    N, C, H, W = feat.shape
    feat_proto_distance = -torch.ones((N, self.class_numbers, H, W)).to(feat.device)
    for i in range(self.class_numbers):
        feat_proto_distance[:, i, :, :] = torch.norm(self.objective_vectors[i].reshape(-1,1,1).expand(-1, H, W) - feat, 2, dim=1)
    return feat_proto_distance
```

This is original function using norm distance with shapes:
self.objective_vectors[i].reshape(-1,1,1).expand(-1, H, W): torch.Size([256, 128, 224])
feat: torch.Size([8, 256, 128, 224]) with 8 is batch_size

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`torch.nn.CosineSimilarity`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CosineSimilarity.html).

The structure of your code is not very clear to me, but you could probably do something like:

```
def feat_prototype_distance(self, feat):
    distance_metric = torch.nn.CosineSimilarity(dim=1)
    N, C, H, W = feat.shape
    feat_proto_distance = -torch.ones((N, self.class_numbers, H, W)).to(feat.device)
    for i in range(self.class_numbers):
        feat_proto_distance[:, i, :, :] = distance_metric(self.objective_vectors[i].reshape(-1,1,1).expand(-1, H, W), feat)
    return feat_proto_distance
```

Comment: I also tried this way but no success. Because their shape is different. self.objective_vectors[i].reshape(-1,1,1).expand(-1, H, W) is the center of the cluster whose shape is [256, 128, 224] , and feat is the vectors whose shape is [8, 256, 128, 224] with 8 is batch_size

Comment: Help me pls! :((((